# Is there anyway to make this div come back when you scroll to top again

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

So i got this div animate out of the page perfectly but whenever i scroll back up it's still out of the page i tried an if/else statement but it doesn't come back, anyone could help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300){
            $('.offer').stop().animate({ top: '+= 10' }, 10, "linear");
        }
        else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 300){
            $('.offer').stop().animate({ top: '-=10' }, 10, "linear");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you show the not working fiddle?

Comment: Yup here it is:
http://jsfiddle.net/HjFH4/177/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //Keep track of last scroll
  var lastScroll = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScroll){
        $('.offer').stop(true).animate({ top: '+= 100px' }, 10, "linear");
    }
    else{
        $('.offer').stop().animate({ top: '-=100px' }, 10, "linear");
    }
    //Updates scroll position
    lastScroll = st;
  });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not quite yet, see here a fiddle of your code in it,
http://jsfiddle.net/HjFH4/181/
it's suppose to go up when you scroll down (faster as normal elements)
and when you scroll back up it's suppose to be in the exact same spot as it was before.
Got an idea's for this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding or removing `10` from the position *every single time* a scroll event is fired.

What you should do instead is have a flag, such as `isFurtherThan300`, which keeps track of whether the position is before or after your cutoff.

Then, perform the animation *only* if `isFurtherThan300` changes.

Comment: Yes that totally makes sense, only problem is i'm not experienced in creating flags at all, this is how far i got but then i get pretty much stuck. 
http://jsfiddle.net/HjFH4/178/

Comment: Well it kinda works but the element doesn't scroll up fast anymore, tried some differend number but doesn't quite work.